# What constructor needed to access many methods in other classes?

Tags: java, testing, constructor

I am having trouble trying to create a simple test with the 4 classes. I want to do something simple where I create a user and it has access to logging in, send email, and logout (as an example). My problem is I don't quite know what to put in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th classes. AppUser class I would like to have the ability to access many classes (ie AppMenu, EmailPage, etc.) So extending would not work.

What should my constructor look like for AppUser to access many methods in other classes? Or do I need other things. Greatly appreciate the help to improve my understanding.

```
/**   First class **/
public class AppTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppUser user = new AppUser();
    user.login();
    user.sendEmail();      
    user.logOut();  
    }
}


/** Second class **/
public class AppUser {  
}


/** Third class **/
public class AppMenu {      
  public void login() {
    System.out.println("I logged in!!!");
  }

  public void logOut() {
    System.out.println("I logged out!!!");
  }
}


/** Fourth class **/
public class EmailPage {   
    public void sendEmail() {
      System.out.println("Send Email"); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make them as class member variables. See below implementation:

```
public class AppTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppUser user = new AppUser();
    user.login();
    user.sendEmail();      
    user.logOut();  
    }
}


/** Second class **/
public class AppUser {  
   private AppMenu am;
   private EmailPage email;

   public AppUser(){
     am = new AppMenu();
     email = new EmailPage();
   }

   public void login(){
     am.login();
   }

   public void logout(){
     am.logout();
   }

   public void sendEmail(){
      email.sendEmail();
   }


}


/** Third class **/
public class AppMenu {      
  public void login() {
    System.out.println("I logged in!!!");
  }

  public void logOut() {
    System.out.println("I logged out!!!");
  }
}


/** Fourth class **/
public class EmailPage {   
    public void sendEmail() {
      System.out.println("Send Email"); 
    }

}
```

So effectively you want to have a user who should be able to login, logout and send email. So you need to wrap all these functionality in user class, which means that tommorow if you make any changes to email sending and login/logout functionality then classes making call to user class are not impacted.

Answer (score 0):

```
private AppMenu appmenu=null;
private EmailPage emailpage = null;
```

AppUser(){
    appmenu = new AppMenu():
        emailpage = new EmailPage();

}

public void login(){
    appmenu.login();
}

public void sendEmail(){
     emailpage.sendEmail();
}

You must define those methods in `AppUser` class also to access as you do